# unreported exception when using Unsafe

Tags: java, exception, unsafe

I have wrote a simple code to use `Unsafe.prefetchRead` on an array and used [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/d98807bff770/test/compiler/6968348/Test6968348.java) test code as a template.

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class Arr {
  static int [] a = new int[3];
  static Unsafe unsafe;
  static int baseOffset, indexScale;
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    a[0] = 10;    a[1] = 20;    a[2] = 30;

    Class c = Arr.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("sun.misc.Unsafe");
    Field f = c.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    unsafe = (Unsafe)f.get(c);

    baseOffset = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(int[].class);
    indexScale = unsafe.arrayIndexScale(int[].class);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
      unsafe.prefetchReadStatic(a, baseOffset+indexScale*i);
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

However I get these errors

```
Arr.java:14: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Class c = Arr.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("sun.misc.Unsafe");
                                                  ^
Arr.java:15: unreported exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Field f = c.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
                                ^
Arr.java:17: unreported exception java.lang.IllegalAccessException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    unsafe = (Unsafe)f.get(c);
                          ^
```

Comment: I suppose you should habe a sound understanding of Java BEFORE messing with the `Unsafe` class. (Hint: read on exception handling)

Comment: yes some info on exception handling is required and what the different kinds of exception does java have and how you are supposed to use it in the code. clear case of not delcaring checked exceptions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it working, change `public static void main(String[] args)  {` to `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {`.

Then [read up on exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).  The [`ClassLoader#loadClass(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) method throws the declared exception `ClassNotFoundException`.  You must handle it, or allow it to be thrown out of your method.  Same for the other two errors.

Comment: Try it.  See if it works.  Then read up on exceptions, and the [`ClassLoader#loadClass()'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: The code in the link you posted includes this line: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {`.  It's pretty explicit: throw the Exceptions you're not handling.

Comment: Excuse me I mixed that with the top level class `Arr`. Thanks.